# Differentiate entries in Block Data with a flag in Fortran77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am initializing a header struct in Fortran 77 in a `BLOCK DATA` . Whereas I have two versions of this *.f - file. One got an update with new functionality but the old version should be still supported.

The new version looks alike:

```
 Block Data INIT_HS
      Implicit None
C
      Include 'hdr_str.inc'
C
      Data (HDR_STRUC (I, NAVA), I = 1, 5)/
     &      CITY   , AREA,
     &      LAT   , LONG,
     &      ELEV,
     &      END/
C
      Data (HDR_STRUC (I, NAVB), I = 1, 3)/
     &      CITY   , CUST AREA,
     &      NAME    , END/
C
      Data HDR_STRING (CODE) /'CODE'/
      Data HDR_STRING (ALT   ) /'ALT'/
      Data HDR_STRING (LAT) /'LAT'/
      Data HDR_STRING (LON) /'LON'/
      Data HDR_STRING (ACCL) /'ACCL'/
END
```

And in the old version some entries are not there:

```
 Block Data INIT_HS
      Implicit None
C
      Include 'hdr_str.inc'
C
      Data (HDR_STRUC (I, NAVA), I = 1, 3)/
     &      LAT   , LONG,
     &      ELEV,
     &      END/
C
      Data (HDR_STRUC (I, NAVB), I = 1, 2)/
     &      CITY   , CUST AREA,
     &      END/
C
      Data HDR_STRING (CODE) /'CODE'/
      Data HDR_STRING (LAT) /'LAT'/
      Data HDR_STRING (LON) /'LON'/
END
```

For the rest of the merged source code, I found a solution in handing over an argument when calling the executable:

```
  DUMMY.exe VERSOLD
```

or:

```
DUMMY.exe VERSNEW
```

So I implemented a function setting a flag which version it is. For normal `PROGRAM, SUBROUTINE` etc. it is no issue but within this `BLOCK DATA` I can not just implement a `CALL GETVERS` ... `IF (VERSOLD) THEN` 
I will get the following Error message from the compiler  `(gfortran -m32 -std=legacy -ffixed-line-length-none -c -g -fno-automatic -fno-second-underscore -finit-local-zero )` (..yes former g77..)

```
Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)
```

Of course I could just implement a second `BLOCK DATA` with a different name.

I really wonder whether there is any other nice solution for this?

Comment: I don't understand.  It seems you are controlling at _run time_ the version to be used (with the command line argument), but the block data program selection is a _compile time_ problem.  Could you please expand on how you expect the differences to come about?

Comment: I see your point. I did not get the entire impact I guess. Is the `BLOCK DATA` only called during the compilation and not during runtime? The fortran-file is not appearing as source file in my debugger during calling the exe . So therefore it is so fixed I can't change it during execution and switch between version old and version new?

Comment: You can't switch between which block data program unit is used at run time, no.  Block data program units provide initial values for the stated entities and those are established before anything like looking at a command line option. For more flexibility you should consider using initializing procedures (relevant questions may be found on SO), but my reason for asking for clarification was to know whether initializing variables which won't be used would be a problem.  That is, can't you just use the "new" block data?

Comment: No I can't because the entries are compared to another struc. I gave up on it, I created a second fortran file, renamed both Block Data and decide now during runtime which one to use ... It is a mess now with all the if's and I am not happy, but no time for refactoring...